# Github Actions yml config multiple paths in a step?

Tags: android, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm trying to migrate my Android project from CircleCI to Github Actions and I have followed guide on Github page. When I reach this part

```
- name: Upload math result for job 1
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
  with:
    name: homework
    path: math-homework.txt
```

the problem I encountered is that I used to have multiple paths and I can't get it to work with the following lines

```
        paths:
          - 'app/build/test-results'
          - 'app/build/tmp'
```

So my question is how can I add multiple paths in this config? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from [description](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/blob/master/action.yml):

*path - A file, directory or wildcard pattern that describes what to upload.*

So, *wildcard* option will work for you:

```yaml
- uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
  with:
    path: app/build/**/*
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But there are also other folders in that directory, is there really no way I can choose just what I need and ignore the rest? As I suppose upload many artifacts would slow down my progress, right?

Comment: Yes. But I suggest you just to play with wildcards. It's powerful mechanism and I am sure that you can find a valid wildcard that will upload exactly what you need. [Example](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact#upload-using-a-wildcard-pattern).

Comment: I will look into it. For now I guess I would just upload necessary files in separated steps!